# underline input field when typing

Tags: android, html, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an input field that is displaying an underline when I start typing text. This is not the autocorrect underline but a black underline as I have tried disabling auto-complete and spellcheck. This only appears on android jelly bean phones.

```
<input type="search" id="searchInput" class="searchInput" placeholder="placeholder" />
```

[image: underline]

I have removed all css from the input tag and nothing I do will disable this underlining.

As soon as i remove focus from the input field the underlining goes away.

Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: It might have something to do with being default behavior for a search field - I'm not sure you should want it to go away.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is the autocomplete feature built into the phone, not based on a webpage setting try something like this:

Simply go into **Settings > Language & input > Android keyboard settings > Advanced settings > and uncheck "Next word prediction"**

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding css to make sure it *doesn't* do that?

```
text-decoration: none;
```